# React Typescript| Uploading Image to Firebase Vague Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, error-handling

I'm trying to save an image to firebase storage. In JS it seems pretty straight forward but I'm a little confused with the error i'm getting in my typescript implementation.

So I have this block of code:

```
  const [banner, setBanner] = useState(File)
 const createDocument = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (banner !== null) {
            var storageRef = storage.ref();
            var fileRef = storageRef.child('banners/' + banner.name)
            await fileRef.put(banner) //this line triggers an error
            db.collection("Products").doc(docID).set({
               //fields here
                banner: await fileRef.getDownloadURL()
            });
        }
    }
```

I get

```
Argument of type '{ new (fileBits: BlobPart[], fileName: string, options?: FilePropertyBag | undefined): File; prototype: File; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer'.
  Type '{ new (fileBits: BlobPart[], fileName: string, options?: FilePropertyBag | undefined): File; prototype: File; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ArrayBuffer': byteLength, slice, [Symbol.toStringTag]ts(2345)
```

And it seems pretty vague to me and I don't really understand where I'm to begin with solving it. Thank you for your time and any feedback will be much appreciated..

Comment: Is banner of type `Blob | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer` ? We cant see from your code